# How to get a y axis ranging from 10^6 to 10^9 in r?

Tags: r, scaling

I have a bar plot showing cell counts (in exponential) versus treatment. The code I use gives me an output scale from 0 till 10^7 but eating up everything below 10^7. I would like to have a custom scale ranging from 10^6 to 10^9 with breaks at 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9.

I have tried using setting the limits and breaks using scale_y_continous but that didn't help. My code is as follows:

```
ggplot(data = Zerohourdata) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = AB.Treatment, y = cfumilli)) + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Plate.ID) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10^6, 10^8), breaks = c(10^6, 10^7, 10^8))
```

Help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and add sample data to turn it into a [MCVE]. For R, there's some great advice at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Lacking your data, this code gives me a plot whose y-axis ranges from `1e+06` to `1e+08` (not sure why you're setting `8` if you are asking for `9`).

Comment: Sorry, that is a mistake, it should be till 9.

@FrankSchmitt Thank you! To both of you the data is as follows :

Treatment::Count
A::20000000
B::50000000
C::47142857

Comment: If your data spans a few orders of magnitude, you might also try `scale_y_log10` or `scale_y_sqrt` or access them using `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")` etc.

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks! That got things sorted.